# How to load a csv file into pandas to use it in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner who is having trouble loading csv files into pandas dataframe.

The code which I am trying to run in a jupyter notebook is:

```
df_census = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
```

Then I have created a function which accepts the dataframe as a function parameter:

```
def explore_df(df):
    df.show()
```

But I am getting error while calling the function

```
explore_df(df_census)
```

The error message is:

```
NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e557e519fd3d> in <module>
----> 1 explore_df(df_census)
NameError: name 'df_census' is not defined
```

Comment: Def explore_df(df) is a function you created, what does it do? Have you actually properly defined it as a function? It seems you didn't, and you are calling an invalid function declaration, hence it's undefined.

Comment: I thought using def before explore_df defined and created the function, then adding(df) to it told it to give information like .shape and .head on a specific file like census.csv. Did I create the function improperly? I am having trouble getting basic info on the csv file to show it has been loaded. That is my first issue.

Comment: Yes but did you actually define the function? Is it like "def explore_df(df): df.head()"? How does Python knows what explore_df is supposed to do?

Comment: I added these commands on the next indented line after the colon, but they gave the name df_census is not defined error. print( df.shape[0] )
    return df.head()

Comment: I am trying to follow an instructor's lead, but maybe I missed a step he used to give the explore function its functionality

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what show() does. If you would like to see what was loaded. Just print it.

```
import pandas as pd

df_census = pd.read_csv('census.csv')

def explore_df(df):
    #df.show()
    print(df)

explore_df(df_census)
```